# How to access a shared folder (A private folder shared with my account by an owner account) with Drive API and Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a file to a shared folder but I can not find a solution. I want to upload to a folder that is shared by an owner account, shared with the account I am logged into.

This is how I get the Drive Folder ID of a parent folder, but I am unable to access a shared folder the same way:

```
  const mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
  String folderName = "Shared Folder Name";

  final found = await driveApi.files.list(
    spaces: 'drive',
    q: "mimeType = '$mimeType' and name = '$folderName'",
    $fields: "files(id, name)",
  );
  final files = found.files;
  if (files == null) {
    return null;
  }

  if (files.isNotEmpty) {
    return files.first.id;
  }
```

Please help me understand how to access a shared folder, so I will be able to upload my pdf file to that folder.

Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting or what response are you getting when running the files.list ? Is it a shared drive where the folder is located?

Comment: I am not able to locate the folder. Yes, the folder is shared to me by another user, from their drive.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the function returns null, because no files are found in that name.